# how to calculate new date that excludes weekends for formula field

Tags: salesforce

Is there a way to write a formula that adds *n* number of days to an existing date that returns a new date, that does not include weekends?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean "Given a day, add any number of days but ensure that the new date does not fall on a weekend?"

If so, your language of choice should readily provide for you a function that determines what day of the week a date is. Usually, 0 is Sunday and 6 is Saturday.

Here's some pseudocode:

```
newDate = myDate + random(1, n); // n is whatever largest integer you want.
//random(1, n) would be give me any number between 1 and n inclusive.

while ((newDate.dayOfWeek == 0) || (newDate.dayOfWeek == 6))
   newDate = myDate + random(1, n);
   // keep on generating a new date until it's not Sunday or Saturday.

// At this point, newDate is guaranteed not to fall on a weekend.
```

Comment: My apologies, I meant using a formula field within Salesforce.